# Virtual fields aren't included by "accessibleFieldsPlugin"

Tags: express, mongoose, casl

Using CASL with Express and Mongoose, when I use `accessibleFieldsPlugin`, the virtual fields aren't included with the results.

Is this a bug, or I have to do some workaround to get them included also? What is the best thing to do in this situation ?

Person model:

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    picture: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ....
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});

personSchema.virtual('picturePath').get(function () {
    if (this.picture != null) {
        return path.join('/', uploadPath, this.picture)
    }
    return null;
});

personSchema.plugin(accessibleRecordsPlugin);
personSchema.plugin(accessibleFieldsPlugin);

module.exports.Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema, 'person');
```

Comment: You can provide custom `getFields` option to `accessibleFieldsPlugin`: https://github.com/stalniy/casl/blob/master/packages/casl-mongoose/src/accessible_fields.ts#L7. It accepts mongoose schema which you can use to retrieve fields

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to maintain if you configure the plugin globally.

Something like this would add all the virtual props (FYI, id is already included).

```
mongoose.plugin(accessibleFieldsPlugin, { 
  getFields: (schema) => Object.keys({...schema.paths,...schema.virtuals})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Stotskyi help, I manage to solve this problem like this (If there is a better code, I highly appreciate any help):

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    picture: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ....
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});

personSchema.virtual('picturePath').get(function () {
    if (this.picture != null) {
        return path.join('/', uploadPath, this.picture)
    }
    return null;
});

personSchema.plugin(accessibleRecordsPlugin);

// Here is the new code
const customAccessibleFieldsPlugin = new accessibleFieldsPlugin(personSchema, {
    getFields(schema) {
        const paths = Object.keys(schema.paths);
        paths.push('id');
        paths.push('picturePath');
        return paths;
    }
});
personSchema.plugin(() => customAccessibleFieldsPlugin);

module.exports.Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema, 'person');
```